# Alternative to "inheritance versus composition?"

Tags: design, design-patterns, inheritance, anti-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does this concept of “favor composition over inheritance” come from?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from)

I have colleagues at work who claim that "Inheritance is an anti-pattern" and want to use composition systematically instead, except in (rare, according to them) cases where inheritance is really the best way to go.

I want to suggest an alternative where we continue using inheritance, but it is strictly forbidden (enforced by code reviews) to use anything but public members of base classes in derived classes.

For a case where we don't need to swap components of a class at runtime (static inheritance), would that be equivalent enough to composition? Or am I forgetting some other important aspect of composition?

Comment: Related discussion on Stack Overflow: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/590790)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156592/composition-vs-inheritance http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/66879/how-do-we-know-to-favour-composition-over-generalisation-is-always-the-right-cho

Comment: If you systematically avoid inheritance everywhere, your code will not be OOP and the benefits of it will be lost on you. That being said, some people don't like OOP, and maybe that's who you're working with.

Comment: Vote-to-closers, I don't think this is a dup, because it's not yet another inheritance vs. composition question, it is asking about a very restricted form of inheritance.

Comment: @Karl - I'm also asking specifically if keeping inheritance but forbidding the use of anything but public members of the parent classes would be acceptable to people who favor composition.

Comment: @Karl: Without a specific example, the question is essentially "Is it *always* right to favour composition over inheritance?" which is also the question in my fourth link.

Comment: @pdr. No. I'm really asking about inheritance where the derived are restricted to use only public members of the parents. Would that be equivalent enough to composition?

Comment: *Would that be equivalent enough to composition?* Equivalent enough **for whom**? Inheritance and composition are different things. Relying exclusively on composition ignores a useful tool, just as relying exclusively on inheritance does.

Comment: @Caleb see Karl's answer below. He is explaining how this solution is not equivalent to composition, what it misses from the composition approach. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Frank: I'm sorry. I guess I don't see what you were trying to achieve or why, but if Karl has cleared up your confusion then it's all good.

Comment: @pdr Here is the story: someone suggested we should use composition rather than inheritance at work. I found that rather radical, so I'm digging into it. I had the idea that maybe we could continue using inheritance, but never allow derived classes to access the implementation of the parent. I wanted to check how that differed from composition. Karl answered that it helps with loss of encapsulation, but still implies perfect substitutability.

Comment: @Frank: Ok, I see what you're saying, but I would strongly recommend reading all the answers to the various conversations above. You probably need to understand the benefits of composition over inheritance before you start fighting that decision. Make no mistake, it is a bad decision to completely forbid inheritance but it's also a bad decision to use inheritance before you fully understand the reasons not to.

Comment: @MrFox That's not quite true. OOP is about interfaces. Inheritance is just a mechanism that happens to be included in most OOP languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're sort of looking at it backwards.  Composition isn't preferred because of some unseen benefit of composition, it's preferred because it avoids the drawbacks of inheritance.  Inheritance adds the significant benefit of substitutability.  However, that benefit comes with the significant cost of tight coupling.  Inheritance is the strongest coupling relationship possible.  If you don't need the substitutability, the coupling cost isn't worth it.

Your restricted version of inheritance addresses its other cost, a loss of encapsulation, but does nothing about the much more significant cost of coupling.

Comment: Thanks Karl, that's the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: This may be the best explanation of this concept I've ever seen.

Answer (score 4):

I think the difference between the two things is in their intent. Is the class you are writing really meant to be used as replacement / specialisation of its Base class or is it just using some functionality? If the First Case is true you should go with inheritance. If the latter is true go for composition. In my experience using inheritance where composition would be appropriate creates a more complex, less understandable and meanigful codebase.