# Inheritance with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework

I'm starting work on a new personal project and I'm looking to get advice in regards to setting up my classes.

My base class is a User. The User class will have the following general properties

- User ID
- User Name
- Password
- Address (this will be a complex/value type)

I will then have a Subscriber class which is a User who has chosen to subscribe to a plan that I offer. The Subscriber class will have its own properties in addition to that of the User including:

- Subscriber ID
- Plan ID
- Date Subscribed
- etc

Is inheritance the way to go here with User being the base class or is a foreign key from the Subscriber to User class the better way? If inheritance is preferred then which method? TPH or TPT?

The plan is to have other classes with the User class acting as the base including Participants and Volunteers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought, along the lines of ['prefer composition to inheritance'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from), is that inheritance isn't needed (nor the best representation of the common 'subscriber' system), and that your User class should have a collection of Subscriptions.

The Subscriptions would be basically the same as you've described them, but without the inheritance piece. A particular Plan's 'Subscribers' would be the collection of Users that have a Subscription to the Plan.

Likewise with Participants and Volunteers.

Answer (score -1):

This is 4 years late but just for anyone else asking, design your data model according to the following points:

- Maintain a `Subscription.cs` class with details like `Currency`, `BillingPlan`, etc.
- Maintain an *abstract* `User.cs` class with details as you've provided.
- Maintain a `Subscriber.cs` class which inherits `User.cs` since all the properties of `User.cs` are *necessary* in `Subscriber.cs`. If only some of the properties are desired, then choose *composition over inheritance*.
- `Subscription.cs` should have a `SubcriberID` GUID as a unique key and a `Subscriber` navigational property. Note that this key is not existent in `Subscriber.cs`.
- If you have any more classes who will need *all* the properties of `User.cs`, let those class simply inherit from `User.cs`. If your application won't follow this strict inheritance, use `interfaces` instead and compose as you desire.